# What is configuration in oracle oem performance graph

Tags: sql, oracle

Same merge statement SQL with different param to update different record in the same table.
When I tested it ,just use 5s~10s.
But it happened itl waiting(tx lock) when i run those SQL in pre release test.it looks like cause too many dml run on the same time
How to improve the itl wait situation without changing INITRANS and PCTFREE parameters setting of table?

Change merge to update or something? 
I need a method to confirm the solution really works.

Comment: What percent of the total time is spent on ITL waits?  Before you worry too much about a specific wait you should focus on the top waits.  The only time I've seen ITL waits take up a significant amount of time was an extreme case with hundreds of identical inserts at the same time.  Do you have a lot of DML on the same table?  Also, since you're using OEM, can you add some SQL Monitoring information?  That can make troubleshooting very easy.

Comment: I found a lot useful message here ,and this is my first question here.Thank you for reply me.let me talk more about this question.

Comment: I am doing a task to improve a batch process time.The method I use is divide the 1 session process into 5 session to update 5 parts data.<br/> in test, it works well,half time improved.<br/>but in release env.The itl wait happen very clearly.90% more  wait is itl waits.<br/> I dig this problem today.<br/>here is some imformation what i digged <br/>

Comment: 1.The table parameters: pctfree 5, initrans 1. <br/>2.The sql is merge into - update,1 session update about 800 records,5 session run in the same time ,will be 4000 records.<br/>3.The table divide into partition.the pctfree and initrans is of the partion <br/>4.I replay the itl wait in test env successful.4 session without commit,and 1 session itl wait for a long time until other session commit <br/>5. but 4 just happen in one partition,I add data to other partition itl didnt happened.

Comment: So that is hard situation now. set pctfree,initrans bigger maybe work.but cant confirm this in test env.<br/>How to exactly solve the problem  is really big question to me.

Comment: By the way. 5 seesion update data wont lock each others by record level

Comment: First it may help to find out exactly what object has the ITL wait.  Try this query: `select * from dba_objects where object_id = <current_obj# from v$active_session_history for relevant waits>;`.  My first guess is this is a bitmap index issue.  For bitmaps, updating a single row can lock many other rows.  (Although I'm not sure if that would show up as an ITL wait issue.)

Comment: The object is the table. i confirmed it by v$statement_xxxx(forgot).and this enq: TX - allocate ITL entry.http://www.dbtuna.com/article/40/enq:_TX_-_allocate_ITL_entry

Comment: but if cause this,i should replayable the issue in same pctfree and initrans partition.but i cant, what is different?

Comment: It could be [MAXTRANS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses007.htm#SQLRF52297).  Although that parameter is now deprecated, unless you are on an old version or the table was created on an old version.